# May I distribute a game engine that is based on textbook examples?

Tags: copyright, licensing

I have purchased several game programming books to start my journey as a game developer. One of them teaches its readers by building a game engine's parts in each chapter until finally you have a complete working game engine. It's bare-bones, but still a game engine.

What exactly am I allowed to do with this engine, as far as releasing an indie game of my own? Is it copyright infringement if I attempt to use the game engine from the book even with my little changes and adjustments?

Comment: You certainly are allowed to use the engine from the book. The point of the book is for you to understand the engine and be able to modify it and build upon it. But if you intend to make games professionally you would be much better off using already existing engines. Both UE4 and Unity3D v5 are free (untill you start earning a lot of money) and the will give you a great experience and ahead start i development.

Comment: Sorry for trimming your question down that much, but you were asking lots of things which are off-topic here and would have gotten your question closed. Please check the [help center](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105161/beginner-game-developer-seeking-advice-help#) before posting questions.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help and this is my second question here so that is understandable. I will check the help center too.

Comment: Also I have Unreal Engine 4 and Unity 3D but believe or not, C++ code looks a lot less intimidating. But I will give a shot thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Book contents usually fall under the copyright of the author. Software developed based on the source code from the book (no matter how much or little you change) is a derived work, meaning you need the permission of the copyright holder.

However, it is usually not in the interest of a textbook author to sue people for following their advice.

Some books have a section somewhere explaining the copyright terms of the code printed in the book. If your book has no such section, I would recommend you to contact the author and ask them to clarify the copyright situation.

Comment: Okay so I just checked the authors copyright information and the code for the book is under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 unported. Meaning I am free to use, modify and distribute the game commercially. Thanks for giving me some clarity.

Comment: Note that some books are very strict on how you may use the code. For example, [Numerical Recipes in C](http://www.nr.com/licenses/) is extremely protective of the routines presented in the book.